# Owl Carousel for custom them for Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2.2.4, custom-theme, slider, owl-carousel

I am creating a custom theme and I need to add banner slider in the home page. I try to use owl carousel and it’s not working. Can you please help

Her is how I try to add slider to home page

1 created a custom home page layout under Magento_Theme/page_layout/1column.xml with below code

```
 <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-header" before="-" />
        <container name="gm-slideshow" as="gm-slideshow" label="Page Slideshow Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="gm-slideshow" before="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="homepage_slider" template="Magento_Theme::html/slider.phtml" />
        </container>

        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

2. created a template file page layout under Magento_Theme/template/html/slider.phtml with below code

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('homepage_slider')->toHtml();?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'owlcarousel'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';
        $(".gm_home_banner").owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: 3000,
            margin:5,
            items : 5,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,5],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [979,5],
            itemsTablet : [768,5],
            navigation : true,
            pagination : false
        });
    });
</script>
```

3 created a requirejs-config.js under Magento_Theme with below code

```
    var config = {
    paths: {
        'owlcarousel' : 'js/owl.carousel.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```

4 added my css under default_head_blocks.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"/>
        <css src="css/owl.carousel.css"/>
        <css src="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <css src="css/george_custom.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</page>
```

5 Then I created a custom block from the Magento backend with below code

```
    <div class="gm_home_banner owl-carousel">
<div class="item"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/George/180.jpg"}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/George/181.jpg"}}" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Slider not loading but it shows the two images

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: did you check if css are actually loaded?

Comment: @ Amit Naraniwal- No error in console

Comment: @magefms- Yes css loaded

Answer (score 0):

You Need to update your owl-carousel script look like:

```
require(["jquery",'Owlcarousel'], function($,Owlcarousel){
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /*This For HomePage Brand Slider.*/
    $(".gm_home_banner").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        margin:5,
        items : 5,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,5],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,5],
        itemsTablet : [768,5],
        navigation : true,
        pagination : false
    });
});
});
```

You need to update your point number 5 **PHTML** File. like this :-

```
<div class="gm_home_banner owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/George/180.jpg"}}" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/George/181.jpg"}}" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Add Whole Class of Owl Carousel in your phtml File

> owl-carousel owl-theme

you have not define **Owlcarousel** in your function.please check your code.

Comment: I update the code based on your recommendation still slider not working, also i get this error . "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at VM4626 owl.carousel.js:1713
    at VM4626 owl.carousel.js:1750"

Comment: in your point no 3         'owlcarousel' : 'js/owl.carousel.min'  replace it with         'owlcarousel' : 'js/owl.carousel'

Comment: I tried that as well and no luck

Comment: the solution that you provided did't work for me so how i accept the answer

Comment: ok No Problem I'm sorry..

Answer (score 0):

> change template file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('homepage_slider')->toHtml();?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'owlcarousel'
    ], function ($, owl) {
        'use strict';
        $(".gm_home_banner").owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: 3000,
            margin:5,
            items : 5,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,5],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [979,5],
            itemsTablet : [768,5],
            navigation : true,
            pagination : false
        });
    });
</script>
```

> change requirejs-config.js

> Add file owl.carousel.min.js Magento_Theme/web/js/owl.carousel.min.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'owlcarousel' : 'Magento_Theme/js/owl.carousel.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```